# Why can I only change the css style once in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to change the backgroundColor of a box between multiple colors using js but I cannot seem to find a way. Is it possible?

```
window.onload = function() {
var example=document.getElementById("example");
var click=0;
example.addEventListener("click", func);

function func(){
    if (click===0){
    example.style.backgroundColor=("red");
    click=1;
    }
    if (click===1){
    example.style.backgroundColor=("blue");}
    click=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The () around ("string") is useless.... FYI

Comment: Because if click is zero you change it to 1 and then right after that you check to see if it is one and change it back to zero. That is what happens when you do not use `else if`

Comment: Or do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m2x541qd/

Comment: A number variable that flips between 0 and 1 should really be a boolean (true or false) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks to see if the value is zero. When it is, it sets it to one. Right after that if statement you see if it is one and set it back to zero.

You need to use `else if` or just `else` so it does not evaluate the next if statement.

```
function func(){
    if (click === 0){
      example.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      click = 1;
    }
    //else if (click === 1) {
    else {
      example.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      click = 0;
    }
}
```

Personally I would just toggle a class

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("#test")
elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
  elem.classList.toggle("on");
});
```

```css
div.example {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.example.on {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="example">Click Me</div>
```